# Como montar uma lista com checkbox partindo de um array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fala galera, blz? Sou iniciante em programação web e estou fazendo uma aplicação hibrida para dispositivos móveis, gostaria de saber como posso preencher uma lista trazendo o nome de um objeto e o seu id dentro de um array em uma função de js utilizando jquery.
Segue o código:

```
 <div class="list-group" id="itensAmigoConta" style="margin-top: 5%">
 </div>
```

Comment: Cuidado com códigos ruins. A resposta que vc aceitou possui problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, e ae, beleza? Você tem que fazer um for percorrendo o seu array e assim ir montando o html dentro da div com .append, inserindo o campo pego pelo array e o seu index, adicionando também um input com o type checkbox e colocando o index como seu id, da seguinte maneira:

```
function exemploLista() {

$("#itensAmigoConta").html("");

for(i in seuArray){
    $("#itensAmigoConta").append("<li >"+
    "<label>"+seuArray[i].campo+""+
    "<input type='checkbox' id='"+i+"'>"+
    "</label></li>");
}
```